# How do I make the code in lib/ automatically reload when the file changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285148/where-should-my-non-model-non-controller-code-live). During development I have to restart the rails app everytime I change the code in lib/ in order for the code changes to take effect. How do I get this code to automatically reload like controllers, models, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Rails) Reloading "lib" files without having to restart server...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114388/rails-reloading-lib-files-without-having-to-restart-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails 3 - Reload lib directory for each request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282655/ruby-on-rails-3-reload-lib-directory-for-each-request)

Answer (score 3):

For **Rails 3**, vary the instructions given in the article from @science's answer. In your `environments/development.rb` file, add the lines:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << File::join( Rails.root, 'lib')
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.explicitly_unloadable_constants << 'MyModuleInLibFolder'
```

Of course, substitute the name of your module for `MyModuleInLibFolder`.

Comment: @science's answer has been deleted as a link-only answer (the link has since rotted, for what it's worth).

Answer (score 1):

```
module ActsAsReloadable
  def self.included(base)
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.explicitly_unloadable_constants << base.name if Rails.env == 'development'
  end
end
```

To use it, simply `include ActsAsReloadable` in your lib/* files and add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

why not just enter

```
load Rails.root + '/lib/your_lib.rb'
```

Comment: Failed unless I used `join`: `load Rails.root.join('lib/your_lib.rb')`

Answer (score 0):

If you already did the previous approaches but doesn't works (like my case), try with `config.reload_classes_only_on_change` in `development.rb`.

Rails 4.2 here ✋