# (Rails) Reloading "lib" files without having to restart server...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, reload

Is there any way in Rails to have the ENV reload "lib" files without having to restart the server?  I'm working with some classes that I have inside a module in "lib".  However, in order to see my changes I must restart the server each time.  I'm guessing this is the way Rails is intended to work, but it is quite tedious when developing library files and/or plugins.

Surely I'm going about this wrong....?

Best

## EDIT 1

Neither answer 1 nor 2 worked for me.  Instead I was presented with errors from the controllers that made use of the Module.  FYI, I have 3 files in my "lib/xmlitems" directory.  I attempted to load that subdirectory then I referenced the single file that "requires" all other files.  Am I to individually load all files?

Comment: Looking at the duplicate target, none of the answers are particularly good. As duplicates require the question to be answered in the target, I'm voting to re-open.

Answer (score 14):

For **Rails 3** and **Rails 4.0**, vary the instructions given in @txwikinger's answer. In your environments/development.rb file, add the lines:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << File::join( Rails.root, 'lib')
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.explicitly_unloadable_constants << '<my modules in lib>'
```

Comment: When I did this, I was using a module called ::Utils.  When I ran my code, it gave me an error, `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Utils`.

Comment: Hm. Could you put your code on pastie.org and share a link?

Comment: Turns out that was my own fault, although I thought I had isolated it using a git diff.  Sorry JellicleCat, unfortunately Stackoverflow locked in my -1. :(  I still can't verify your answer though.

Comment: Worked great, though I removed the brackets from the String that's appended to 'explicitly_unloadable_constants'

Comment: This allows you to reload classes in the lib directory as well, confirmed for rails 4. Thanks!

Comment: *Thank you!* I've spent the last four hours scouring SO and google, trying so many different possibilities. Probably spent more time than I'll save with this working, but I persevered on principle --  autoreloading files between requests should be doable and easy! Your answer accomplishes just that on 3.2.13. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that `explicitly_unloadable_constants` array is an array of constants (class names) but not file names. And one more trouble: on second reload I got an exception: `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MyClass`.

Comment: txwikinger's answer has since been deleted

Comment: Glad I finally found this, works under Rails 4.2.10.... but what it the purpose for explicitly_unloadable_constants << 'MyModuleName' ?

Answer (score -1):

```
module ActsAsReloadable
  def self.included(base)
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.explicitly_unloadable_constants << base.name if Rails.env == 'development'
  end
end
```

To use it, simply `include ActsAsReloadable` in your lib/* files and add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score -3):

There's an easier way: just add

```
config.reload_plugins = true
```

to development.rb

Comment: This didn't work for me.