# How can I force Rails 3.2 to reload mounted rack app per request in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I force Rails 3.2 to reload mounted rack app per request in development mode?

I have mounted [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) app this way

```
 mount API2, :at => "/api2"
```

However rails doesn't reflect changes in app without web server restart.

Comment: is it a `gem`? If its a `gem` you can declare it in your apps `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 5):

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4368838/667158

```ruby
# Reload Grape in development mode
api_reloader = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker.new(Dir["path/to/you/api/dir/**/*"], true) do
  Rails.application.reload_routes! # or do something better here
end

ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
  api_reloader.execute_if_updated
end
```

Comment: change the path "path/to/you/api/dir/**/*" before try it