# Forcing reload of library files that are required by an autoloaded library file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Rails 3.2.3**. I have a Rails app with `/lib` in in my autoload paths. One of my library files is requiring a bunch of files like so

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/foo/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

In development, those files don't reload if I change them. For example, if I modify `/lib/foo/bar.rb`, I will have to restart the server to see those changes. Can anyone suggest a way so that on each request they are reloaded properly?

Answer (score 3):

If you have those files in your autoload path:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

then you shouldn't need to require them. Have you tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4368838/233720)?

Comment: You have a trailing paren!

Answer (score 3):

`require` doesn't play very nicely with rails' autoloading system.

`require_dependency` will do pretty much what require does but keeps the autoloading system in the loop so that the loaded constants will get unloaded at the end of the request. You may need to ensure that the files are in rails' autoload paths

Comment: Once I removed `require` reloading happened automatically if module file changed. Thanks @Frederick Cheung

Answer (score 0):

You have to add or un comment the line.

**config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)**

to your Application class in config/application.rb