# Rails app running on Pow not reloading for changes in /lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack-pow

After many googling I've tried adding both of these to my config and yet reloading doesn't happen:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

I make changes to files under /lib but refreshing in Pow doesn't reload the changes

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you refreshing the browser or restarting the app?

Comment: @veritas1 refreshing, restarting it (say, by `touch tmp/restart.txt`) works of course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to restart pow after changing files in /lib because Rails initializes objects here as it starts up and doesn't load them again after having started up (so changes while the server is up won't make a difference). To overcome this, you have a few options:

1. You may want to look at using `require_dependency`.
2. You can restart Pow by touching the restart.txt file: `touch ~/.pow/restart.txt`
3. For a more convenient solution if you're changing your lib folder a
   lot, add [anvil](http://anvilformac.com/) to handle your restarts
   easily.
4. If you don't want to do this, just add your classes to the /app path
   into a new folder.

Comment: But isn't that what autoload_paths is for? to tell rails what more to reload?

Comment: That's to autoload not auto-reload. If you really want to, there's some hacks here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282655/ruby-on-rails-3-reload-lib-directory-for-each-request