# Reflect changes to environment.rb without restarting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails server seems to need restart when I change config/environment.rb.
Is there a way to reflect the change without restarting server?

A gem for it or something like that exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `environment.rb` file is one of the main initialiser files for starting your app and can't really be reloaded on each request because reloading that is nearly the same as restarting the whole app. I'm guessing there are some variables in there that you want to change without restarting every time. Well instead of putting them in there, you could create a `.rb` file in the `lib` directory. That code gets run when the app is started and is useful for defining custom classes, etc.

To make it automatically reload it on each request you need to use `eager_load_paths` in your `config/application.rb`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282655/ruby-on-rails-3-reload-lib-directory-for-each-request) specifies how to do that.

Comment: It seems a little more tricky than I thought. I'd restart server when it's necessary. Thanks for the answer!